# Генерация pdf из HTML

Tags: php, mysqli, pdf

Есть страница сайта(внутреннего). В нем отображается в реальном времени количество товара(т.е. что-то забрали или добавили, на странице это отображено).
Задача сохранить данные в pdf каждые 3 дня, в папку на сервере с текущей датой. С чего начать, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Я бы копал в cторону генерация pdf cредcтвами PHP/Python/Node.js. Уверен, еcть множеcтво фрэймворков...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+pdf тут даже банально посмотреть можно, как делают в основном. В целом есть либы, которые из html генерят pdf. смотреть на mpdf, fpdf, dompdf и т.п.

Comment: Наводящий вопрос: есть ли эти данные в БД?

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/html-to-pdf-freeware-linux-osx-windows-software/

Comment: @Alexey Да, практически все данные из базы идут.

Comment: @SergeySmirnov простейший вариант - dompdf/mpdf, библиотеки для генерации pdf из html. Однако у них есть проблемы с CSS3, и если страница достаточно сложная, возможно придется использовать https://github.com/its404/php-puppeteer (node.js поднимает сервер с движком хрома, потом PHP обращается к нему для генерации PDF)